# Python program which contains several python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I want to write a python program, for example, main.py which contains two or more python programs(test1.py,test2.py..etc,.) which are placed in some other directories in these all of these programs has its own methods with parameters(test1.py,test2.py..etc,.). I tried some but cases were failed which contains parameters within the program. IS there any easy way to access several programs within one main python program?

Comment: what do you mean by 'accessing several programs'? are you looking for modules and packages?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @syfluqs means, I have the first program on one folder second one in other folder and my main program in the third folder, I desire that the first folder may have more than one python program and I want to call all of them on my main.py which placed in the third folder, think so now you may get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. You can use `import` to load other python files:

```
# Use file1.py, file2.py
import file1
from file2 import func2

file1.func1()
func2()
```

In case your other files are programs, and not simply variables, class and functions, you can avoid executing the code in this programs as follows:

```
# file1.py(old)

def func1():
   ...

func1()  # Execute func1 when this file is loaded.
```

```
# file1.py(new)

def func1():
   ...

if __name__=='__main__':
   func1()  # Execute func1 when this file is loaded.
```

The code inside the `if __name__=='__main__'` block is only run if this is the first file loaded.

```
# Use file1.py, file2.py
import file1
from file2 import func2

file1.func1()
func2()
```

If you'd like to organize those files into a directory, you must create a 'module'. This simply requires that you place an empty `__init__.py` in the directory:

```
 + test.py
 + mymodule/
    + file1.py
    + file2.py
```

```
# Test.py. Use mymodule/file1.py, mymodule/file2.py
import mymodule.file1
from mymodule.file2 import func2

file1.func1()
func2()
```

This will work if mymodule is in the current directory when run. (ie. you ran `python test.py` and not `python a/b/c/test.py`.

For a detailed answer, see http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: well ... should't that be `func2()`?

Comment: Yes.. I will fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @user48956, yes but I have each python program in each separate folders, for example, file1.py in D:\folder1 and file2.py in E:\folder2 likewise and I cannot achieve it. That's my problem I cannot access python files which are in other directories

Comment: @user48956 what if func1() has some parameters as func1(a,b,c) in file1

Comment: Have you tried adding those parameters to the function definition in file1 and calling the function with those parameters?